# Why is only utility icons allowed on lightning:buttonIcon and other types like standard?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service, slds

I want to use a standard icon as button in my application but it is not allowed in `lightning:buttonIcon`.

If I use `lightning:icon`, it does not contain `onclick` handlers.

If I enclose it in div or any other html tag, I can't use `event.getSource()`/`event.taget/event.currentTarget` or any other event handler methods to get attribute value (like `'v.value'`) from that element because of locker service restrictions.

1. Why are other types not allowed in lightning:buttonIcon?
2. How to use standard icons in lightning:buttonIcon?

Comment: When we try to use Standard Icon, it gives an error as: `lightning component 'buttonIcon' only support "utility" icons` which answers your first question. Second question doesn't seems to be possible with lightning at the moment.

Comment: what is your use case?

Comment: @RahulSharma : I know it gives error and standard icons are not allowed. My question is why has salesforce have done that? It would be easier to use other icons as buttons had this restriction not been there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rahul said, lightning:buttonIcon supports utility:icons only. If you want to use Standard or Action icons then you can do as below.

Cmp:

```
<button name="lead" class="slds-button">
    <span data-value="{!value}" onclick="{!c.controllerFunction}">
          <lightning:icon iconName="standard:lead" size="small"/>
    </span>
</button>
```

And you can get data-value like this.
Controller:

```
controllerFunction: function(component,event,helper) {

   var value = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value");
   console.log('value:::',value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [vote](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LnirQAC) for this idea to request Salesforce.